# json_query filter with bug?

Tags: ansible, juniper, junos-automation

I have a situation.

When I try to use json_query filter in ansible-playbook return this error:

> {"msg": "Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:\ninvalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'"}

I solve this with `replace ('-','_')` filter.

**Have I other way to solve this?**

complete code here:

```yaml
---
# tasks file for mpls-lsp

- name: Colete informações do protocolo osfp
  junipernetworks.junos.junos_rpc:
    rpc: get-ospf-neighbor-information
    output: json
  register:
    _data

- name: Aplica as configurações padrão em RT-BRAS.*
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ _data2 | json_query('ospf_neighbor_information[0].ospf_neighbor[*].neighbor_address[0].data') }}"
  vars:
    _data2: "{{ _data.output | replace ('-','_') }}"
  when: "'device_roles_bras' in {{ group_names }}"
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your question is missing a sample data structure of your `_data` variable as quite a few people here won't have access to a junos device to play around and cannot guess the exact returned information in your situation anyway. I suggest you [edit](/posts/68487920/edit) your question and add it. You might also want to read [how to create an MCVE](/help/mcve)

Comment: Well actually don't bother. It would have been easier with your data to go straight to target but I got it. Think about it for next answer. Crafting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

`"ospf-neighbor-information"[0]."ospf-neighbor"[*]."neighbor-address"[0].data`

## Full Story

> I solve this with `replace ('-','_')` filter.

This is actually quite dangerous as this replaces dashes for underscores absolutely everywhere in the input, identifiers and values. But if we now look at your resulting jmespath expression

> `json_query('ospf_neighbor_information[0].ospf_neighbor[*].neighbor_address[0].data')`

we can infer that all your identifiers where previously using `-` as a separator

In the above expression, you are using unquoted identifiers. If you look at [jmespath specification for identifiers](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#identifiers), you  will see that unquoted ones cannot contain dashes.

> ```
> identifier        = unquoted-string / quoted-string
> unquoted-string   = (%x41-5A / %x61-7A / %x5F) *(  ; A-Za-z_
>                        %x30-39  /  ; 0-9
>                        %x41-5A /  ; A-Z
>                        %x5F    /  ; _
>                        %x61-7A)   ; a-z
> quoted-string     = quote 1*(unescaped-char / escaped-char) quote
> unescaped-char    = %x20-21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-10FFFF
> escape            = %x5C   ; Back slash: \
> quote             = %x22   ; Double quote: '"'
> escaped-char      = escape (
>                        %x22 /          ; "    quotation mark  U+0022
>                        %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C
>                        %x2F /          ; /    solidus         U+002F
>                        %x62 /          ; b    backspace       U+0008
>                        %x66 /          ; f    form feed       U+000C
>                        %x6E /          ; n    line feed       U+000A
>                        %x72 /          ; r    carriage return U+000D
>                        %x74 /          ; t    tab             U+0009
>                        %x75 4HEXDIG )  ; uXXXX                U+XXXX
> ```

So if your identifiers contain dashes, you must quote them (and note that quoting identifiers is made with double-quotes)

You can transform your `json_query` task as below to make it work on your original data (you might have to adapt as I didn't have your original structure and had to guess a bit...)

```yaml
- name: Aplica as configurações padrão em RT-BRAS.*
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ _data.output | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: >-
      "ospf-neighbor-information"[0]."ospf-neighbor"[*]."neighbor-address"[0].data
  when: "'device_roles_bras' in {{ group_names }}"
```